# What is the use of setHeader and recipientList in Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

```
from("file:src/data?noop=true").to("jms:incomingOrders");

            // content-based router
            from("jms:incomingOrders")
            .choice()
                .when(header("CamelFileName").endsWith(".xml"))
                    .to("jms:xmlOrders")  
                .when(header("CamelFileName").regex("^.*(csv|csl)$"))
                    .to("jms:csvOrders")
                .otherwise()
                    .to("jms:badOrders");        

            from("jms:xmlOrders")
            .setHeader("customer", xpath("/order/@customer"))
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    String recipients = "jms:accounting";
                    //System.out.println("hii1"+recipients);
                    String customer = exchange.getIn().getHeader("customer", String.class);
                    //System.out.println("hii2"+customer);
                    if (customer.equals("honda")) {
                        recipients += ",jms:production";
                        //System.out.println("hii3"+recipients);
                    }
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("recipients", recipients);
                }
            })
            .recipientList(header("recipients"));

            // test that our route is working
            from("jms:accounting").process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Accounting received order: " 
                            + exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName"));   
                }
            });                
            from("jms:production").process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Production received order: " 
                            + exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName"));   
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Input XML FORMAT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order name="motor" amount="1000" customer="honda"/>
```

I am new to Apache Camel so help me guide through code here. This code in copied from Camel in Action and explain use of  Recipient List based on same EIP. So after dividing based on xml and csv it is passed to recipientList where i am struggling with the use of

> setHeader

and

> .recipientList(header("recipients"));

So it will help if anybody can explain me the flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need your message to be broadcasted to **multiple** recipients

- The `multicast` is the pattern to use for a **static** set of recipients:
- The `recipientList` is the pattern to use for a **dynamic** set of recipients. In such case, you need to tell Camel where to find/how to evaluate **! at run-time !** this list of recipients. There are numerous ways to express this, and one if these is to say: "Please look into the message header name 'foo' which will contain the exact list". But of course, your Camel route has to prepare/populate (at run-time) the header content 
  (population which is done in your example in the
  process(new Processor() {...} step)

Comment: But what exactly is the use of setHeader?? why he is adding header with customer name?? Where it is further used down in chain????  Besides that what does "exchange.getIn().setHeader("recipients", recipients);" do? why again set header?

Comment: @smitshah Header `customer` is set in Java DSL `.setHeader("customer", xpath("/order/@customer"))` and used in Processor `exchange.getIn().getHeader("customer", String.class)`.... And header `recipients` is set in Processor and used in `recipientList`... I don't understand what confuses you.